# Swift SFSpeechRecognitionTask is not canceled

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, sfspeechrecognizer

I am working with Speech Recognition in Swift and have a problem with canceling `SFSpeechRecognitionTask`.

I have implemented the following logic:

- I have a mic button
- Speech is being recognized while button is pressed
- When the mic button is released I need to finish the speech recognition, to get the results in completion block (`recognitionTask` is used for it). So I use `stopRecording()` function for this purpose. This function works properly.
- I also need to cancel `recognitionTask` when I do some other logic. So I need `recognitionTask` to **stop immediately the completion handler and to return error or result**. For that purpose I'd written `cancelTask()`. I've tried different variants of this function, but non works. The problem is that I always get completion after some delay when app is running with slow internet connection (for example edge).

I've checked `recognitionTask.isCanceled` just after `recognitionTask?.cancel()` and this property is always `false`. Any ideas why this is not working?

```
    func startRecording() throws {
    guard speechRecogniser.isAvailable else {
        // Speech recognition is unavailable, so do not attempt to start.
        return
    }
    if let recognitionTask = recognitionTask {
        // We have a recognition task still running, so cancel it before starting a new one.
        recognitionTask.cancel()
        self.recognitionTask = nil
    }

    guard SFSpeechRecognizer.authorizationStatus() == .authorized else {
        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization({ _ in })
        return
    }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
    try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
    try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

    recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
        throw SpeechControllerError.noAudioInput
    }

    recognitionTask = speechRecogniser.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { [unowned self] result, error in
        if let result = result {
            self.delegate?.speechController(self, didRecogniseText: result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
        }

        if result?.isFinal ?? (error != nil) {
            inputNode.removeTap(onBus: SpeechController.inputNodeBus)
        }
    }

    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: SpeechController.inputNodeBus)
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: SpeechController.inputNodeBus, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
        self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
    }

    audioEngine.prepare()
    try audioEngine.start()
}

/// Ends the current speech recording session.
func stopRecording() {
    audioEngine.stop()
    recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
}

func cancelTask() {
    audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
    audioEngine.stop()
    recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
    recognitionTask?.cancel()
    recognitionTask = nil
    speechRecognizer = nil
    recognitionRequest = nil
}
```

Comment: I don't see any call to `cancelTask`

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini as I wrote `cancelTask` is called when I do some other logic, for example press another button

Comment: did you try to look at `SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate` ?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini what do you mean? `SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate ` has no methods to cancel `SFSpeechRecognitionTask`, it will only send you results

Comment: I mean, you may want look at it. You have a callback called `func speechRecognitionTaskWasCancelled(_ task: SFSpeechRecognitionTask)` which might give you an idea about status of your `recognitionTask`

Comment: @Danny How you have solved this problem?

Comment: @Danny Man, how did you solve it? This issue is killing me.